# assign with for loop products to warehouse, some product have product couple that has to be the same warehouse. How to get corresponding product id

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements, append, corresponding-records

*The first part of my code makes sure that the productids with highest loss (if not stored in warehouse 1), are stored in warehouse 1. But then some of this products are in a product couple, which means that they have to be in the same warehouse. I have a dataframe with the two columns, first column is productid and second column is productid2 of the couples. How can I write a code in my loop that finds the corresponding product id, and also do the same actions for the corresponding product id.
So "**

```
if capacityleft >= row["#pickUpBoxes"]:

                warehouse.append("warehouse1")

                capacitysum = capacitysum + (row["#pickUpBoxes"])**


*code*
warehouse = []

capacity = 960.0

capacitysum = 0

for index, row in dfAvgDailyProfitLoss_PickUpBoxes.iterrows():

    capacityleft = capacity - capacitysum

    if capacityleft >= row["#pickUpBoxes"]:

        warehouse.append("warehouse1")

        capacitysum = capacitysum + (row["#pickUpBoxes"])

        for row["product-id"], line in zip(x, y):
            
            if capacityleft >= row["#pickUpBoxes"]:

                warehouse.append("warehouse1")

                capacitysum = capacitysum + (row["#pickUpBoxes"])

    else:

        warehouse.append("warehouse2")

dfAvgDailyProfitLoss_PickUpBoxes["warehouse"] = warehouse
print(dfAvgDailyProfitLoss_PickUpBoxes)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have to make a loop in the loop for: if product id x is in a product couple with product id y, y needs to be added to the warehouse list too, and the capacity should be decreased with the number of pickup boxes of this product id y. Also product y should not be stored again. Product Couples can be find in another df: "dfProductCouples". After the first if with three lines, the code should be replaced with a code that makes the loop for product couples.